# OpenAPI `multipart/form-data` enum

Tags: swagger, openapi

See the following spec for POST where the `content` is `multipart/form-data` of `application/json`.
How can I specify using an [enum](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/) that the `multipart/form-data` can be either `image/png` or `image/jpeg`?

The following passes validation, but if you try to use the `openapi-generator generate` to create client, you would have issues with the enum values trying to be generated as binary values.

```
/players:
  post:
      operationId: createPlayer
      summary: create a new player.
      description: Create a new player.
      tags:
        - Players
      requestBody:
        description: Optional parameters.
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              required:
                - id
              properties:
                address:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    address_line:
                      type: string
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              required:
                - tag_picture
              properties:
                tag_picture:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                  example: label.jpg
                  enum:
                    - image/png
                    - image/jpeg
```